# How to hide the last horizontal line in data grid?

Tags: wpf

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MergeGridTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// test1window.xaml 的交互逻辑
    /// </summary>
    public partial class test1window : Window
    {

        DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
        public test1window()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var Doctors = new List<Doctor>()
            {
                new Doctor(){Name="Zhang",Score=15,Address="Chengdu",Dept="Neike"},
                new Doctor(){Name="Zhang",Score=18,Address="Chengdu",Dept="Neike"},
                new Doctor(){Name="Zhang",Score=17,Address="Chengdu",Dept="Neike"},
                new Doctor(){Name="Liu",Score=15,Address="Chengdu",Dept="Thke" },
                new Doctor(){Name="Liu",Score=18,Address="MianYang",Dept="Thke"},
                new Doctor(){Name="Liu",Score=17,Address="MianYang",Dept="Thke"}
            };
            TestGrid.ItemsSource = Doctors;
        }
    }
    class Doctor
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Dept { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MergeGridTest"
        xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2" x:Class="MergeGridTest.test1window"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="test1window" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Background="LightBlue" x:Name="TestGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="50" IsReadOnly="True" 
                  CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                  RowHeight="30" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFCB0202" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Score" Binding="{Binding Score}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: image show](https://note.youdao.com/yws/public/resource/ae451287f619092cc8b0485de1ddc297/xmlnote/AC1E5BD45A1C46A190271C395E0BBAA2/23392)

as show,I don't want to show the last line's (the last red line) under line in this data grid, but other horizontal line show normally, how to do it?

the data grid's line setting is for all lines, so I can't set the line visual style only the last line.

Comment: As a quick-hack, you could always use Snoop (or the Visual Inspector in recent versions of VS) to find out how to reference the last line and use reflection to override it.

Comment: I don't know why this question has been downvoted -4+2 because I think this is a good question to ask about WPF because WPF doesn't have anything like CSS's `:last-of-type` or `:last-child` selectors. If you are someone who has downvoted this question, please post a comment reply explaining why you downvoted it.

Comment: In the WPF usually you see data from source bound to the control. Remove data from the source and you will not see those data  in the control.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this by the following steps:

1.Set the `GridLinesVisibility` property of your `DataGrid` to `None`.(To hide all the horizontal and vertical grid lines)

2.Replace your `DataGridTextColumn` with `DataGridTemplateColumn` and put your cell content wrapped in a `Border` in the `CellTemplate` of `DataGridTemplateColumn`

3.Set the `BorderThickness` of the `Border` to `"0,1,0,0"` and `Margin` to `"-1"`, and `BorderBrush` to any color you like

Here is a possible sample snippet based on your original code :

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MergeGridTest"
        xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2" x:Class="MergeGridTest.test1window"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="test1window" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Background="LightBlue" GridLinesVisibility="None" x:Name="TestGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="50" IsReadOnly="True" 
                  CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                  RowHeight="30" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFCB0202" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="-1">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Score">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="Black"  Margin="-1">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Address">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="Black"  Margin="-1">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```